# Merging two assosiative arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have two associative arrays.

```
array ( [apple]=>1 [banana]=>2 cocunet => 3)
```

and other array is

```
array ( [apple]=>2 [banana]=>3 cocunet => 4)
```

now i want to merge my array like that

```
array ( [apple]=>1,2 [banana]=>2,3 cocunet => 3,4)
```

Comment: so `$array['apple']` would become an `array` of `1` and `2`?

Comment: Do you mean `array ( [apple]=>array(1,2), [banana]=>array(2,3), cocunet =>array(3,4))`

Comment: That's the same as my follow-up question just worded properly xD

Comment: yes i got ans array_merge_recursive does the trick ... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such array in PHP. The thing you want can only be done by creating multidimentional arrays.

```
$a1 = array( 'apple'=>1,'banana'=>2,'coconut'=> 3);

$a2 = array( 'apple'=>2,'banana'=>3,'coconut'=> 4);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_merge_recursive($a1,$a2));
echo "</pre>";
```

For this you can use the array_merge_recursive() function.

PHPFiddle: http://3v4l.org/5OCKI

Comment: Maybe check existing answers prior to posting your own; if within a minute or so then understood but 5 minutes is a bit cheeky.

Comment: The methodology of your answer is identical to the one posted five minutes prior to yours, so I do not see how this is funny whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks Ozan Kurt ur solution is perfect

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to be a string then this should work:

```
 foreach( $array_1 as $fruit => $num) {
        if(array_key_exists($fruit, $array_2)){ //check if key from array_1 exists in array_2
             $final_array[] = array($fruit => $array_1[$fruit].','.$array_2[$fruit]); //concatenate values from shared key
        }
    }
```

`print_r($final_array)` will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [apple] => 1,2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [banana] => 2,3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [coconut] => 3,4
        )

)
```

Comment: Actually it's not completely clear what he wants.  He doesn't indicate whether he wants the result to be string or multidimensional array.  This answer will provide string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array1 = array("apple" => 5, "banana" => 1);
    $array2 = array("banana" => 4, "coconut" => 6);
    print_r( array_merge_recursive( $array1, $array2 ) );
?>
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [apple] => 5 [banana] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 ) [coconut] => 6 )
```

I only used two elements in each of the primary arrays to demonstrate the output prior to having any groups existing, i.e. non-array value.

Comment: OP @umair what `return`, the `print_r` was used to demonstrate the Output.